# Degree of minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Can someone please help with this question.

> Prove that degree of minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q} $ of $\zeta_{7} $ , a primitive 7th root of unity is not a prime number.

I thought as $\zeta_{7} $ =$1^{1/7} $  so  I can write $1^{1/7} $ =x which implies $x^{7} $ =1 . So, it's prime.

But answer is not prime. So, I am missing some concept.

Can anyone please tell what mistake I am doing.

Comment: Can you name a rational root of $x^7 - 1$? If you can, this means the polynomial isn't minimal.

Comment: @RghtHndSd Sure, I'll name it Steve

Comment: Check out this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722850/minimum-polynomial-of-a-root-involving-the-7th-root-of-unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is, $x^7-1$ is not the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_7$, as it is not irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_7$ is the irreducible factor $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ of $x^7-1$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: how is $x^{6}$ + ....+x +1 is minimal polynomial , you need to prove it!!

Comment: Yes. Recall the definition of minimal polynomial $\alpha$ over $F$. It is the irreducible monic polynomial  over $F$ with $\alpha$ as a root. Now that polynomial is a cyclotomic polynomial which is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ (can be shown from Eisenstein's criteria). Now $\zeta_7$ is a root of $x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ but not a root of $x-1$, so it must be root of the other factor.

Comment: Eisenstein crieria can't prove $x^{6} $ + $x^{5} $ +... +1 to be irreducible . So, how can I prove $  x^{6} $ + $x^{5} $ +... +1 to be irreducible.

Comment: Well, this prove is a beautiful problem by its own. Just search it by "cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible" or,  I guess any standard book has it right after the section of Eisenstein's criteria.

Comment: Although I am giving a rough idea of the proof. Let denote that polynomial by $p(x)=\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}$ then you can show $p(x+1)$ is irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's criteria using the prime 7. Now $p(x+1)$ is irreducible implies $p(x)$ is so.

Comment: Which result you are using to prove that irreducibility of p(x+1) implies irreducibility of p(x) ?

Comment: Well, you try to prove if $p(x)$ is reducible then for any $a$, $p(x+a)$ is also reducible. It is easy.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal polynomial should be irreducible. But all its roots are non-real roots of 1. Since coefficients are real (even rational) all roots of the minimal polynomial must be decomosed into pairs $(a, \bar a)$ , so the number of roots and the degree must be even. The only even prime is 2 but a quadratic rational polynomial cannot have a non-real root which is the seventh root of 1. So, indeed, the degree of minimal polynomial is not prime.